# How do I make buckets according to date in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My data looks like this -

```
{
   'field1' : 123
   "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-04T13:35:57.621Z")
},
{
   'field1' : 123
   "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-04T13:35:57.621Z")
},
{
   'field1' : 123
   "timestamp" : ISODate("2012-10-04T13:35:57.621Z")
},
{
   'field1' : 123
   "timestamp" : ISODate("2012-10-04T13:35:57.621Z")
},
{
   'field1' : 123
   "timestamp" : ISODate("2012-10-04T13:35:57.621Z")
}
```

I am trying to get result something like this -

```
{ "date" : '2012-10-04', "count" : 3 },
{ "date" : '2017-10-04', "count" : 2 }
```

Right now my query is -

```
db.train_data.aggregate({ $group: { _id: { $dayOfYear: "$timestamp"},count: { $sum: 1 } } })
```

It aggregates the dates just right but does not display the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your data, this agg expression:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id:"$timestamp", n:{$sum:1}}}
  ,{$addFields: {datestr: {$dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$_id"}}}}

              ]);
```

yields

```
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2012-10-04T13:35:57.621Z"),
    "n" : 3,
    "datestr" : "2012-10-04"
}
{
  "_id" : ISODate("2017-10-04T13:35:57.621Z"),
  "n" : 2,
  "datestr" : "2017-10-04"
}
```

If you want to agg on JUST the Y-m-d portion, group on that instead:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$addFields: {datestr: {$dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$timestamp"}}}}
,{$group: {_id:"$datestr", n:{$sum:1}}}

              ]);
```