# How to use bucket of mongodb for date moving time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For example, I have the data as below.

```
{  
   "id": 1,
   "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-03T10:00:00.000Z")
},
{
   "id": 2,
   "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-03T21:00:00.000Z")
},
{
   "id": 3,
   "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-04T13:00:00.000Z")
},
{
   "id": 4, 
   "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-04T22:00:00.000Z")
},
{
   "id": 5,
   "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-05T13:00:00.000Z")
}
```

And I have to move the time adding 5hrs.
So I can add this aggregate in '$match'.

```
$gte: new Date(new Date('2019-10-03T00:00:00.000Z').setHours(new Date('2019-10-03T00:00:00.000Z').getHours() + 5 )
$lte: new Date(new Date('2019-10-05T23:59:59.999Z').setHours(new Date('2019-10-05T23:59:59.999Z').getHours() + 5 )
```

But finally, I want to get this result.

```
{
   "2019-10-03":
        [
          { "id": 1, "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-03T10:00:00.000Z")}
        ],
   "2019-10-04":
        [
          { "id": 2, "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-03T21:00:00.000Z")},
          { "id": 3, "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-04T13:00:00.000Z")}
        ],
   "2019-10-05":
        [
          { "id": 4, "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-04T22:00:00.000Z")},
          { "id": 5, "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-10-05T13:00:00.000Z")}
        ]
}
```

How can I get this result by some aggregate function? 
Could you recommend some ideas? Thank you so much for reading it.

I watched similar answer, but my case is different since the time has to be moved.
[How do I make buckets according to date in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571842/how-do-i-make-buckets-according-to-date-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `$group` stage with a non-trivial `_id` field.

The special number (18000000) is the amount of miliseconds in 5 hours.

try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
          "$dateToString": {
              "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
              "date": {
                    "$add": [
                      "$timestamp",
                      18000000
                    ]
              }
          }
        },
      "list": {
        "$addToSet": "$timestamp"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

On your input, this returns:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "2019-10-05",
    "list": [
      ISODate("2019-10-05T13:00:00Z"),
      ISODate("2019-10-04T22:00:00Z")
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2019-10-03",
    "list": [
      ISODate("2019-10-03T10:00:00Z")
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2019-10-04",
    "list": [
      ISODate("2019-10-03T21:00:00Z"),
      ISODate("2019-10-04T13:00:00Z")
    ]
  }
]
```

Later, you can sort it if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. it s awesome!!